# NestJS with Swagger: Cannot destructure property 'prototype' of 'type' as it is undefined

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I got a class `UserWhereInput` as follows:

```
@ApiExtraModels(
    StringFilter,
    StringNullableFilter,
    DateTimeFilter,
    DateTimeNullableFilter,
    BoolNullableFilter,
)
export class UserWhereInput {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(UserWhereInput) },
            {
                type: 'array',
                items: {
                    $ref: getSchemaPath(UserWhereInput),
                },
            },
        ],
    })
    AND?: UserWhereInput[] | UserWhereInput

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(UserWhereInput) },
            {
                type: 'array',
                items: {
                    $ref: getSchemaPath(UserWhereInput),
                },
            },
        ],
    })
    OR?: UserWhereInput[] | UserWhereInput

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(UserWhereInput) },
            {
                type: 'array',
                items: {
                    $ref: getSchemaPath(UserWhereInput),
                },
            },
        ],
    })
    NOT?: UserWhereInput[] | UserWhereInput

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringFilter) }] })
    id?: StringFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { type: 'string', format: 'date-time' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(DateTimeFilter) }],
    })
    createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | Date | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        nullable: true,
        oneOf: [
            { type: 'string' },
            { type: 'string', format: 'date-time' },
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(DateTimeNullableFilter) },
        ],
    })
    updatedAt?: DateTimeNullableFilter | Date | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringNullableFilter) }] })
    email?: StringNullableFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringNullableFilter) }] })
    mobile?: StringNullableFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringFilter) }] })
    username?: StringFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringNullableFilter) }] })
    password?: StringNullableFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'boolean' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(BoolNullableFilter) }] })
    isEmailConfirmed?: BoolNullableFilter | boolean

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'boolean' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(BoolNullableFilter) }] })
    isMobileConfirmed?: BoolNullableFilter | boolean

    // todo
    // @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: () => RoleListRelationFilter })
    // roles?: RoleListRelationFilter
    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'boolean' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(BoolNullableFilter) }] })
    isSuperAdmin?: BoolNullableFilter | boolean

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        nullable: true,
        oneOf: [
            { type: 'string' },
            { type: 'string', format: 'date-time' },
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(DateTimeNullableFilter) },
        ],
    })
    lastLoginAt?: DateTimeNullableFilter | Date | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        nullable: true,
        oneOf: [
            { type: 'string' },
            { type: 'string', format: 'date-time' },
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(DateTimeNullableFilter) },
        ],
    })
    lastLogoutAt?: DateTimeNullableFilter | Date | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringNullableFilter) }] })
    refreshToken?: StringNullableFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringNullableFilter) }] })
    identifierToken?: StringNullableFilter | string
}
```

and another class `RoleListRelationFilter`:

```
@ApiExtraModels(RoleWhereInput)
export class RoleListRelationFilter {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: () => RoleWhereInput })
    every?: RoleWhereInput
    @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: () => RoleWhereInput })
    some?: RoleWhereInput
    @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: () => RoleWhereInput })
    none?: RoleWhereInput
}
```

and `RoleWhereInput`, in which the `UserRelationFilter` also contains `UserWhereInput`:

```
@ApiExtraModels(
    StringFilter,
    DateTimeFilter,
    DateTimeNullableFilter,
    StringNullableFilter,
    BoolNullableFilter,
    RoleTranslationListRelationFilter,
    UserRelationFilter,
    UserWhereInput,
)
export class RoleWhereInput {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(RoleWhereInput) },
            {
                type: 'array',
                items: {
                    $ref: getSchemaPath(RoleWhereInput),
                },
            },
        ],
    })
    AND?: RoleWhereInput[] | RoleWhereInput

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(RoleWhereInput) },
            {
                type: 'array',
                items: {
                    $ref: getSchemaPath(RoleWhereInput),
                },
            },
        ],
    })
    OR?: RoleWhereInput[] | RoleWhereInput

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(RoleWhereInput) },
            {
                type: 'array',
                items: {
                    $ref: getSchemaPath(RoleWhereInput),
                },
            },
        ],
    })
    NOT?: RoleWhereInput[] | RoleWhereInput

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringFilter) }] })
    id?: StringFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        oneOf: [{ type: 'string', format: 'date-time' }, { type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(DateTimeFilter) }],
    })
    createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | string | Date

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        nullable: true,
        oneOf: [
            { type: 'string', format: 'date-time' },
            { type: 'string' },
            { $ref: getSchemaPath(DateTimeNullableFilter) },
        ],
    })
    updatedAt?: DateTimeNullableFilter | string | Date

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringNullableFilter) }] })
    userId?: StringNullableFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        nullable: true,
        oneOf: [{ $ref: getSchemaPath(UserRelationFilter) }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(UserWhereInput) }],
    })
    user?: UserRelationFilter | UserWhereInput

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringFilter) }] })
    name?: StringFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringFilter) }] })
    slug?: StringFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(StringNullableFilter) }] })
    description?: StringNullableFilter | string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'boolean' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(BoolNullableFilter) }] })
    enabled?: BoolNullableFilter | boolean

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, oneOf: [{ type: 'boolean' }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(BoolNullableFilter) }] })
    isDefault?: BoolNullableFilter | boolean

    //todo

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: () => RoleTranslationListRelationFilter })
    translations?: RoleTranslationListRelationFilter
}
```

`UserRelationFilter`:

```
@ApiExtraModels(UserWhereInput)
export class UserRelationFilter {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, type: () => UserWhereInput })
    is?: UserWhereInput
    @ApiPropertyOptional({ nullable: true, type: () => UserWhereInput })
    isNot?: UserWhereInput
}
```

it works fine until I uncomment

```
    // @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: () => RoleListRelationFilter })
    // roles?: RoleListRelationFilter
```

in `UserWhereInput`, with the error shown in the title:

```
Cannot destructure property 'prototype' of 'type' as it is undefined.
```

Is this related to the circular dependency or the misuse of the `@ApiExtraModels`? Thanks in advance.

Expected to work fine

Comment: It seems that it's caused by the misuse of the @ApiExtraModels. After moving all of this decorators onto controller's methods, it works right now. The doc is pretty confusing as the descriptions here docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#extra-models and here docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators have conflicts against each other.

Comment: We had the same error message, but it was caused by one of the parameters of `@ApiExtraModels` being undefined.